# show just the diagonal values of this heatmap

Tags: matrix, seaborn, heatmap, diagonal

do you know if there is a way to show just the diagonal values of this heatmap?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [the `mask=` parameter](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html?highlight=heatmap#seaborn.heatmap) to choose which cells to mask (and therefore which to show).

You can use [numpy's `eye()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html?highlight=eye#numpy.eye) function to quickly generate the mask

```
uniform_data = np.random.rand(5, 5)
diag = ~np.eye(*uniform_data.shape, dtype=bool)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, mask=diag)
```

[image]